# How to randomly draw an element from a list according to defined probabilities

Tags: php, random

I would like to write a function in PHP which allows to randomly draw an element from a list according to defined probabilities.

For example:

For an argument with the input `(x = 20, y = 15, z = 35, t = 30)`, the function should have a 20% chance for x, 15% for y, 35% for z and 30% for t

Any ideas?

Comment: do you want weighed real randomness or do you want to enforce those odds over, say, 100 draws ?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is the code?

Comment: I want to do a rand(0,100) , using the random function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an input array mapping element to weights, like

```
['x' => 20, 'y' => 15, 'z' => 35, 't' => 30]
```

A simple solution to this problem is basically two steps:

1. Generate a random number

   ```
   $rand = rand(1, array_sum($weights));
   ```
2. Iteratively sum your array of elements => weights until your random number lies between the previous sum and the next sum.

   ```
   $min = 0;
   foreach ($weights as $element => $weight) {
       $max = $min + $weight;
       if ($rand > $min && $rand <= $max) {
           // $element is the one you want
       }
       $min = $max;
   }
   ```

As far as making it into a function, there's a bit more to it, you may want to validate that your input adds up to 100, etc., but you probably have a better idea of how you want that part to work than I do.